# Change URL in PHP with Hidden Back URL

Tags: php, json

**I have this URL:**

`http://i.ytimg.com/sb/MiG5jPmyDFI/storyboard3_L1/M0.jpg?sigh=GjsoNjq0eJwVMu4MnwgUu0Ufbf0`

**I want to Change the URL Like This:**

`http://i.playit.pk/sb/MiG5jPmyDFI/storyboard3_L1/M0.jpg?sigh=GjsoNjq0eJwVMu4MnwgUu0Ufbf0`

**If I change the URL like this:**

`http://i.example.com/sb/MiG5jPmyDFI/storyboard3_L1/M0.jpg?sigh=GjsoNjq0eJwVMu4MnwgUu0Ufbf0`

BUT, this URL is not working and did not show the image

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you want to change it to `i.playit.pk`, why are you changing it to `i.example.com` instead?

Comment: @Barmar i want to show URL image of `i.ytimg.com ` via my domain URL Like `i.playit.pk` but when i replace i.ytimg.com with my domain they not work visit the link of i.ytimg.com and I.playit.pk you can understand my question

Comment: Are you looking for [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html)?

Comment: I still don't understand the part about changing it to `i.example.com`. What does that have to do with your domain `i.playit.pk`?

Comment: I think this is work but i can't under stand this coding

Comment: i want to pass `i.ytimg.com` with my domain name `i.example.com` i want to show image with my domain name instead of `i.ytimg.com`